# How to upgrade my iPhone 4 to iOS7 from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, iphone, apple, ios

I want to upgrade to iOS7 on my iPhone 4.  Is there any way I can do that without installing a virtual machine? I currently run Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need iTunes to install iOS 7 on the iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. You don't need Ubuntu nor is a computer of any kind involved in the process of upgrading to iOS 7. However, if you want to install iTunes in Ubuntu anyway, I would recommend using a program called Wine to do that (http://winehq.org). It is available for Ubuntu and is a program that allows you to use and install Windows programs in Linux. Also, Wine is not an emulator, meaning that Windows programs run at full speed because Wine is an implementation of the Windows kernel. When you download Wine, I highly recommend installing Wine 1.6 instead of the Wine 1.7 beta. Hope this helps.